# Are there any general conversational Dialogflow chatbots that I can download and import into my own agent?

Tags: dialogflow-es

I'm looking for a Dialogflow zip file that I can import into an agent that has at least 1,000 intents prebuilt already. But, an agent with the limit of 2,000 intents would be ideal. Hopefully, these intents include some of the most common things said to a chatbot.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You most probably won't get all in one FAQ.
But what you can do is create several knowledgeBases in Google DialogFlow using FAQ URL's.
And then you can use it from an agent in DialogFlow.

FAQs site example: [link](https://www.smtusa.com/blog/posts/10-amazing-faq-page-examples-and-why-you-need-one.html#.Yin2wxBBw1I)